# How can i force a template-update in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, polymer

How is it possible to show changes of existing items in a dom-repeat template in polymer?

i tried really all i could think of and i could find in the polymer documentation or in the web. but nothing works. below you find a html-page that uses a small list and tries to change one entry in the list to another value when you click the change button. But the only thing that would change the item in the list next to the change-button is the line that is commented out. all the other lines try it, but fail.

i understand that re-rendering a template is a time-consuming task and that it only should take place when it is necessary and that polymer tries to avoid it as much as possible. but why is it not possible for me (from the view of the code the god of their world ^^) to force a render on purpose?

the method of creating a complete new object, deleting the old item from the list and inserting the new object (thats what the commented line does) is a workaround, but it is a really huge effort, when the items are more complex and have properties or arrays that are not even displayed.

What am i missing? What did i not try? I would be very glad if anybody could tell me what i could do to achieve such a (from my point of view) simple and very common task.

EDIT (solved):
the solution of Tomasz Pluskiewicz was partly successful. but i updated the code to show my current problem. the name of the item is bound using the method format(...). when a button is clicked the item will be removed from the list. this works good. but if you remove the last item of the list, then the new last item in the list should get the name "Last". this also works, when the name is bound directly to the property name. but if i want to do some formatting of the name (surround it with # for example) then the display of this item is not updated.

EDIT2 (partially solved):
The next example that doesn't work, occurs when a value inside the method that is called for displaying a value changes. This can be seen in the example if a change-button is clicked multiple times. It increases an internal counter and the corresponding text will display this value. But this is only true for the first change of the counter. Subsequent clicks won't change the display again. The display shows the value of the counter after the first click. But if another change button is clicked, then the text in front of this button shows the increased counter value. But also only once. It also doesn't display changes on subsequent clicks. The notifyPath-method seems to check if the value changed, but doesn't consider that inside the method that is used for displaying the value, something could have been changed to show the data in another way.

i included a partial solution in this example. If the method that gets called has a parameter that changes when something in the method is changed, then the update will be executed. This can be seen in the second variable that is bound with the parameter displayEnforcer - format(item.name,displayEnforcer). This variable is set to a random value everytime the counter is changed. And this triggers the display update.

But this is a really strange solution and should not be necessary. it would be great if someone has a better solution to this problem.

```
<link rel="import" href="components/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="components/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<dom-module id="polymer-test">
  <template>
    <table>
      <template id="tpl" is="dom-repeat" items="{{list}}">
        <tr>
          <td>{{item.id}} - {{format(item.name)}}- {{format(item.name,displayEnforcer)}}</td>
          <td><paper-button raised on-tap="tapDelete">delete</paper-button></td>
          <td><paper-button raised on-tap="tapChange">change</paper-button></td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </table>
  </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
  Polymer(
  {
    is: "polymer-test",
    properties:
    {
      count: {type: Number, value:0}
     ,list: {type: Array, value: [{id:0,name:"First"}
                                 ,{id:1,name:"Second"}
                                 ,{id:2,name:"Third"}
                                 ,{id:3,name:"Fourth"}
                                 ,{id:4,name:"Fifth"}
                                 ,{id:5,name:"Last"}
                                 ]}
     ,displayEnforcer: {type:Number,value:Math.random()}
    },
    format: function(name,dummy)
    {
      return "#" + name + " - " + this.count + "#";
    },
    tapChange: function(e)
    {
      this.count++;
      this.displayEnforcer = Math.random();
      this.notifyPath("list." + (e.model.index) + ".name","changed");
    },
    tapDelete: function(e)
    {
      if(this.list.length == 1)
        return;
      this.splice("list",e.model.index,1);
      if(this.list.length > 0)
        this.list[this.list.length-1].name = "Last";
      this.notifyPath("list." + (this.list.length-1) + ".name",this.list[this.list.length-1].name);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `notifyPath` to refresh binding of single list element's property:

```
tapChange: function(e) {
  this.notifyPath('list.' + e.model.index + '.name', 'changed');
}
```

See: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2068#issuecomment-120767748

---

This way does not re-render the entire repeater but simply updates the necessary data-bound nodes.

**EDIT**

Your `format` function is not getting updated because it doesn't use the notified path which is an item's name. When you remove an element, the index of that element within the rendered repeater doesn't change, even though the actual item changes. In other words, when you remove fifth element, the index 4 is still 4.

As a workaround you can add `item.name` to `format` call so that it is refreshed when you notify that path:

`<td>{{item.id}} - {{format(index, item.name)}}</td>`

You don't even have to use that value in the example. It's enough that the binding is reevaluated.

Comment: wow, great. this is at least a solution that i can work with. thank you very much :) but i still would like to have it more easy, when i update a item in a function, not knowing, which properties will change: can i tell the template to update the complete item, not just a property of it?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve my issue. I have to dig a little deeper to create an example that reproduces the problem. i will update the question as soon as i made it.

Comment: I updated the question. The problem seems to be the function-call i use for data-binding instead of binding a property directly.

Comment: Great, thank you. That made my day and my template work. :) I tried everything except placing the property in the function call. even giving the item itself didn't help. Great solution, thank you. This will help me at different places in my web app :)

Comment: You're welcome. It's great because I actually learn some of that stuff on-the-fly. So thank you too :).

Comment: After a weekend of changing things in my webapp, i stumbled over an issue, that still is not solved by this. the update works only if the data has changed. but if the data is the same and i just have something changed in the function that is called to display the value, then the display doesn't change. I will change the question with an updated example of this issue.

Comment: i have changed the example in the question to show the new problem.

Comment: At this point I'm not sure I follow. Your's is probably a very synthetic example but, by the looks of it, I think you're approaching the problem in a wrong way. Do you intend to count 'change' clicks? Binding doesn't fire on subsequent clicks, because you notify unchanged value. You must bind to clicks directly so that incrementing them refresh bindings. See how I modified your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/fuhBpKiRsJZGHvuWwgRs?p=preview. There could be a better way, because currently all counters are refreshed, but it works

Comment: thanks for the example, but this is not what i am trying to achive. the count is just an example for a value that is completly intern to the function "format" that provides the value for the display. this value could be set elsewhere in code and changing this value should give me the possibility to update the items. also this could be not only one value but multiple values that the function uses to calculate the display value.

Comment: also these values inside the function can change, when i work on the code. and in this case i don't like to have to find all the places in the app where this function is called to bind to a display value. it simply should update the value when i call notifyPath. it should not matter, if the data of the path has changed or not, if it is bound to a function. or at least i would like to have an additional parameter (like forceupdate or something like this) to tell notifyPath to update under all circumstances.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I will be able to help you further with this question. Please try asking on Polymer's GitHub about the `notifyPath` problem.

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. I am very glad that you could help me understanding whats going on. I have a workaround with my random variable that works like a charme. it is still a workaround and i think it should be possible to achieve this in a less messy way, but it works and i can use it. but i would never have found the workaround without your help. thank you very much for your work :)